# Combine different sets of operations with a list of numbers in Python

Tags: python

Let's say we have a list of numbers in Python:

```
l = [50,10,20,30,40]
```

I want to:

1. See the result of combining the numbers with + and - in different orders,
2. find what set of + and - combinations would provide a result that is closest to 0.

For example, imagine that we have the "set" of operations

```
s1 = [-,-,-,+]
```

then if we apply s1 to l we would get

```
50-10-20-30+40 = 30
```

If we were to apply

```
s2 = [+,+,-,-]
```

then we would have

```
50+10+20-30-40 = 10
```

(So that, in this case, s2 is the best choice, since it's closest to 0)

What could I do to solve this problem?

Comment: Share your efforts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert arithmetical operation symbols to python function you can use `dict` which will match symbol with function from [`operator`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html) module:

```
import operator

operations_map = {
    "+": operator.add,
    "-": operator.sub,
    "*": operator.mul,
    "/": operator.truediv
}
```

To process lists of integers and operators you can use next function:

```
def process(numbers, operations):
    if len(numbers) - 1 != len(operations):
        raise ValueError(f"There're {len(numbers)} numbers and {len(operations)} operations.")
    result = numbers[0]
    for i in range(1, len(numbers)):
        if operations[i - 1] in operations_map:
            result = operations_map[operations[i - 1]](result, numbers[i])
        else:
            raise ValueError(f"\"{operations[i - 1]}\" is not valid operation.")
    return result
```

Usage:

```
process([50, 10, 20, 30, 40], ["+", "-", "+", "+"])
```

---

To find sequence of operations with closest to zero result you can generate permutations of operators using [`itertools.permutations()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) and find min result using [`min()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#min):

```
from itertools import permutations

def closest_to_zero(numbers, operations):
    return min(
        ((process(numbers, current), tuple(current)) for current in permutations(operations)), 
        key=lambda x: abs(x[0])
    )

value, chain = closest_to_zero([50, 10, 20, 30, 40], ["+", "-", "+", "+"])
```

---

To get all possible combinations from set of possible operators you can use [`itertools.product()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product), where `repeat` argument will be set to `len(numbers) - 1`:

```
from itertools import product

def closest_to_zero_patched(numbers, operations):
    return min(
        ((process(numbers, current), tuple(current)) for current in
            product(operations, repeat=len(numbers) - 1)),
        key=lambda x: abs(x[0])
    )

value, chain = closest_to_zero_patched([50, 10, 20, 30, 40], {"+", "-"})
```

Comment: This is a really good answer. Only one question, how would you go about declaring the operations but not the number of operations there. Right now, I have to indicate, say, two "+" and two "-".  For example, we would like to use "+","-" but not tell it how many times it can be used, but rather have it create combinations of those two with the number list to satisfy the conditions of finding the combination of operations that would get us closer to 0.

Comment: @CarlosMedina, [`itertools.product()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) is what you need. Check edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a nearly oneliner (not necessairly the most efficient one):

you can code your list of operators with `True` for `+` and `False` for `-` and add an additional `True` value for the first element of the `l` list (if you always want this element to be added) so that your `s1 = [-,-,-,+]` list looks like the following:

`s1 = [True, False, False, False, True]`

Then using `compress` function from `itertools` package you get your result with:

```
from itertools import compress

sum(compress(l, s1)) - sum(compress(l, [not i for i in s1]))
```

which essentailly first sums all elements associated with `+`'s and then substracts all elements associated with `-`'s.